# A problem about polynomial

Tags: prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Let $P(x)$ is an integer polynomial, deg$=n$, irreducible on $Z[x]$. $a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$,$...$,an are roots of $P(x)$. Prove that if  $p$ is a prime number then  $p|(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)-(a_1^p+a_2^p+....+a_n^p)$ . (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the roots are irrational $p\mid ...$ does not actually make sense.

Comment: nah, we have a1^x+...+an^x is an integer number, x=1,2...,n. so it's still right